# Serch in mongdb inner objects

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Currently I was just using retrieving responses from my form, but now I need to do search in my responses. This is the structure of my form database:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("628fb1db596e46baf54fb8fc"),
        "current_version": 1,
        "form_name": "Attack on forms",
        "history": [
            {
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "client_id": "99",
                        "client_name": "Foo Baar",
                        "values": {
                            "values": [{"daora": "man"}],
                        },
                    }
                ],
                "version": 0,
            }
            {
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "client_id": "66",
                        "client_name": "Irwin",
                        "values": {
                            "values": [{"x1": "x1"}],
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "client_id": "77",
                        "client_name": "Levi",
                        "values": {
                            "values": [{"x1": "x1"}],
                        },
                    },
                ],
                "version": 1,
            }
        ],
        "id": "3faef4ec-a6ea-40d4-8c8d-a5fb14cb2e4b",
        "is_active": True,
        "user_id": "3003",
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("628fb2668aa89decf6b88d18"),
        "current_version": 1,
        "form_name": "u suario as b",
        "history": [
            {
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "client_id": "66",
                        "client_name": "Irwin",
                        "values": {
                            "values": [{"xxxxx": "xxxxx"}],
                        },
                    }
                ],
                "version": 0,
            },
            {
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "client_id": "66",
                        "client_name": "Irwin",
                        "values": {
                            "values": [{"ccccc": "ccccc"}],
                        },
                    }
                ],
                "version": 1,
            }
        ],
        "id": "1c728313-38ea-4ae7-9750-a3dc3f9c02bd",
        "is_active": True,
        "user_id": "3003",
    },
]
```

I need to do two different searchs:
1 - search responses by `client_name` in a specific `form` with the `current_version` of this form, so if I search for `Irwin` or `Irw` or `Irwi` in the form with id `"3faef4ec-a6ea-40d4-8c8d-a5fb14cb2e4b"` it will retrieve something like:

```
"responses": [
   {
      "client_id": "66",
      "client_name": "Irwin",
      "values": {
         "values": [{"x1": "x1"}],
      },
   }
]
```

2 - Search responses by `client_name` in all forms with current_version of each form,so if I search for `Irwin` or `Irw` or `Irwi` I'll retrieve something like it or simillar:

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("628fb1db596e46baf54fb8fc"),
        "current_version": 1,
        "form_name": "Attack on forms",
        "history": [
            {
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "client_id": "66",
                        "client_name": "Irwin",
                        "values": {
                            "values": [{"x1": "x1"}],
                        },
                    }
                ],
                "version": 1,
            },
        ],
        "id": "3faef4ec-a6ea-40d4-8c8d-a5fb14cb2e4b",
        "is_active": True,
        "user_id": "3003",
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("628fb2668aa89decf6b88d18"),
        "current_version": 1,
        "form_name": "u suario as b",
        "history": [
            {
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "client_id": "66",
                        "client_name": "Irwin",
                        "values": {
                            "values": [{"ccccc": "ccccc"}],
                        },
                    }
                ],
                "version": 1,
            }
        ],
        "id": "1c728313-38ea-4ae7-9750-a3dc3f9c02bd",
        "is_active": True,
        "user_id": "3003",
    },
]
```

I'm accepting suggestions about the database structure too

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, one option is using `$filter` with `$regexMatch`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {id: "3faef4ec-a6ea-40d4-8c8d-a5fb14cb2e4b"}},
  {$project: {
      data: {$first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$history",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$this.version", "$current_version"]}}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      responses: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data.responses",
          cond: {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this.client_name", regex: "Irw"}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - 1st](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6ODpH2dbNRd)

The second question has a solution which is a small variation of the first one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      history: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$history",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$this.version", "$current_version"]}}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$set: {
      "history.responses": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$history.responses",
          cond: {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this.client_name", regex: "Irw"}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - 2nd](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xqoNmw2p4uF)